# Datatable show number and column sum with dot as thousand separator and comma as decimal separator

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

I'm using datatable for showing expense amount and to sum columns, That's is working, but I want to show amount and sum total using dot as thousand separator and comma as decimal separator. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">

    
</style>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" /> 
    
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h3 align="center">E X P E N S E&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;L I S T </h3>  
      <table class="table display table-hover table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" id="example" >
          <thead style="text-align: center; background-color: #01caca;color: white; font-weight: bold;">
              <tr>
                  <th style="text-align:center">
                      Account
                  </th>
                  <th style="text-align:center">
                        Month Year
                  </th>
                 <th  style="text-align:center">
                       Amount
                  </th>
                  <th  style="text-align:center">
                       Amount in USD
                  </th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
              <tr>
                  <th style="text-align:left">
                   Total
                  </th>
                  <th style="text-align:center">

                  </th>
                  <th style="text-align:center">
                  
                  </th>
                  <th style="text-align:center">
                  
                  </th>
              </tr>
          </tfoot>
         <tbody>
         <?php
                include "dbconnection.php";
                $sql = $connect->query( "SELECT * FROM  expensemonthly,accounts,exchange WHERE expensemonthly.account_id=accounts.account_id ORDER BY expensemonthly.account_id");  
                while ($row=$sql->fetch_array()) {
            ?>
                <tr >
                    <td style="text-align:left"><?php echo   $row[name] ?> </td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row[yearmonth] ?></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row[amount] ?> </td>  
                    <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row[amount]*$row[rate]?> </td>

                </tr>
            <?php 
            }
            ?>       
  
         </tbody>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
      var editor; 

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable(
        {

            "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                var api = this.api();
                nb_cols = api.columns().nodes().length;
                var j = 2;
                while(j < nb_cols){
                    var pageTotal = api
                .column( j, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return Number(a) + Number(b);
                }, 0 );
          // Update footer
          $( api.column( j ).footer() ).html(pageTotal);
                    j++;
                } 
            }
        }
    );
        });

 
</script>
```

I Attached an image showing my code output (and in red how should be the number format).
I dont know how to do it, Please any ideas? [image]